# Mac error code once hard drive has been erased

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm doing research for a Television series and need to show a basic error message on a Mac laptop after the device operating system and drive had been wiped.

I need to show this simply as a prompt and as I'm not a programmer wanted to make sure this code looked correct.

This is some Windows code as an example.

```
C:\>mkdir con
The directory name is invalid.

C:\>
```

I know this may not be a usual request for this forum but appreciate if someone could help.

Thank you.

Comment: Would fit better on apple.stackexchange.com than here. Interesting question though!

Answer (score 0):

Once a Mac laptop has been formatted/wiped without an operating system the system boots with a question mark folder because it can not find an operating system.

[image: question mark folder on boot]

If you're wanting to show a more terminal prompt instead you could show something like single user mode boot. Something along the lines of [image: single user mode boot]

The first couple of seconds in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVzbryWqpAI show what it looks like when booting into single user mode.

Edit:

A few commands you could run, they would need to be doctored though since they will output actual information if its there, could be `diskutil list` which lists available disks via disk utility. The output looks like

```
~  
[0] ❯ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS L33T H4X0RZ            *248.4 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 65837530-BE8E-49A5-B660-AB09A61B5858
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

Another option is `diskutil info /dev/disk0` or `diskutil info /dev/disk1` (details pulled from previous command)

it outputs something like

```
~
[0] ❯ diskutil info /dev/disk1                                                   
   Device Identifier:        disk1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1
   Part of Whole:            disk1
   Device / Media Name:      L33T H4X0RZ

   Volume Name:              L33T H4X0RZ

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /

   File System Personality:  Journaled HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                  Journal size 24576 KB at offset 0x11502000
   Owners:                   Enabled

   Content (IOContent):      Apple_HFS
   OS Can Be Installed:      Yes
   Recovery Disk:            disk0s3
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 PCI
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              66C54FBD-891D-3C3D-9C6B-9DE1126CF3F7
   Disk / Partition UUID:    65837530-BE8E-49A5-B660-AB09A61B5858

   Total Size:               248.4 GB (248391270400 Bytes) (exactly 485139200 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        40.6 GB (40572178432 Bytes) (exactly 79242536 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes
   Allocation Block Size:    4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                No

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 Yes
   Solid State:              Yes
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

   This disk is a Core Storage Logical Volume (LV).  Core Storage Information:
   LV UUID:                  65837530-BE8E-49A5-B660-AB09A61B5858
   LVF UUID:                 58F68144-FD10-4E7E-83EC-9849F9AAC1D7
   LVG UUID:                 9E898582-1E95-4E37-B6EC-DB4A938EEBA8
   Fusion Drive:             No
   Encrypted:                Yes
```

Comment: The terminal look is what I am after. Is there a short hand I could use in a few lines to get across the fatal error? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Added a few commands - those are just two i can think of off the top of my head, perhaps someone else might have some better ones that may look more error like than I could think of.

Comment: Appreciate you helping. Thanks